# Why am I getting only a single circle in the canvas?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

[image: Target Picture]

So I want my output something like this.

```
var circlePath = new Path.Circle(new Point(0, 0), 25);
        circlePath.strokeColor = 'black';
        var copy = [];
        for(var i=0;i<=10;i++){
        var j=100;
        copy[i]= circlePath.clone();
        copy[i].strokeColor = 'red';
        copy[i].position = new Point(j, 0);
        j=j+100;
    }
```

Hence, I just used a variable to shift the copy to a new point. But it doesn't work and just displays a single circle.

[image: My canvas output]

Comment: Have you tried using the `moveTo()` method instead of directly setting the position of the item? I also think you can try to call the `closePath()` for each item.

Comment: `j` is always 100. Move the declaration of `j` outside of the loop.

Comment: You are initializing your variable `j` inside the `for` circle. Every iteration it assumes the same value of 100.

Comment: Thank you. Now it seems like a stupid question.